# Increase the command timeout limit in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework (and MVC). One of my modules is taking more than 50 seconds to load the data to grid. The webpage is timing out when it crosses 30 seconds.

The ideal way would be fine tune my stored procedure since it takes more than 50 seconds to return the results. I am looking to increase the timeout limit from default 30 seconds to 1 minute at least.

I tried the following ways but no luck:

```
1. I have set the connection timeout at web.config file but it is not working

2. I tried something like this

public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
{
      Database.SetCommandTimeout(9000);
}
```

The 2nd approach works well when I run the solution through visual studio but when I deployed the same code in the Server, this approach is not working.

I think some configuration needs to be changed at server level during deployment but I am not sure about it.

Can anyone please help me on this. I am hitting my heads for the past two days but no luck.

Comment: optimize your procedure

Comment: What database connection are you using.You can add a connection timeout property to increase the length of the db connection.

Comment: ASP.NET, MVC or not, doesn't deal with data access. This is an Entity Framework question. You didn't provide any relevant information though, no data access code, query or stored procedure so it's impossible to help

Comment: What does your data access code do? Are you using transactions, keeping them open for too long? What does that stored procedure do? Are you blocking yourself perhaps? How do you call the stored procedure? The `SqlCommand` object itself has a `Timeout` property

Comment: There are many possible timeouts. Which exact exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably overridden by the web server.

In eg. IIS, it's set in a websites configuration:
Advanced Settings > Behavior > Limits > Connection Time-out (seconds)

There should be something equivalent on other web servers.